# Calling a service from a router

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to call a service from a router. Below is how the code is structured.

```
angular.module('DTApp',[...]);
var dtAction = angular.module(...).controller(...);
dtAction.service('MenuService', menuService);  /* Service defined here */

dtAction.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    MenuRouter($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider);
});

var menuService = function() {
    this.getMenuItems = function() { return ... };
}

var MenuRouter = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, MenuService) {
   console.log(MenuService) /* Shows undefined */
}
```

Comment: Did you inject module which contains MenuService? I think it should be injected here: `angular.module('DTApp',[...]);`

Comment: 1. You are calling `MenuRouter` explicitly, angualar is not doing any dependency injection for you. Hence, the third argument is undefined. 2. Only providers and not actual services are available during the configuration phase. If you post what you are trying to do in `MenuRouter`, we may find a better way to structure your app.